# How to create a downloadable feature expansion system in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to add a feature into an app, however since the feature isn't part of the app main features. We wanted to exclude it from the app when the user first download the app. The idea is that; the user can then enable the feature which would trigger the app to download the expansion codes (screen, methods, .etc) to add to the app.

I've looked around and found things that seems to do something akin to this like Code Push but this doesn't really fit the requirement since it's for pushing update to all users instead of the ones that enabled the feature.

The closest thing I can think of is creating a bundle file and importing it into the app using something react-native-dynamic-bundle. However, even though I managed to create a ".bundle" file and load it into the app, I do not know how to actually use codes from the ".bundle" file.

So the question remains; is this kind of thing possible with React Native? And if yes, is there any place that actually points to how to do this?

Comment: Is there any solution? I'm also trying to solve the dynamic feature delivery using react native.

Comment: @NaveenKumarHS unfortunately I didn't remember finding any. The idea was stopped after some time, and I didn't continue to research it.